# Passing filename as URI parameter - how to secure?

Tags: asp.net, security, model-view-controller

I'm writing a simple log browser for web application. Server lists all log files, user may pick one of them and server displays its contents. The environment is ASP.NET MVC.

Passing filename in URI is dangerous - a simple trick is to use `"..\..\web.config"` to display the configuration file along with all passwords. I obviously need to secure the script, such that it will allow access only to specific files. Simplest method is to check, whether passed filename contains sequences `\` or `..` and reject such queries.

My question is: is this solution safe enough? Or should I choose completely different approach?

---

My proposed solution (to discuss):

```
public LogData GetLog(string file)
{
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Logs/");
    string fileToOpen = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*")
                .Where(f => Path.GetFileName(f) == file)
                .FirstOrDefault();

    if (fileToOpen != null) 
    {
        // Process
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal

Comment: An easy solution would be to enumerate the files and store them in a database/datastore with a GUID as an ID - then you could pass that GUID instead of a filename.

Comment: @Steve As I wrote, this is a log browser. Log files usually are not stored in the database, so I would debate on simplicity of this solution :)

Comment: I meant storing the log path and GUID in a database(updated as they are created etc)

Answer (score 0):

You could manage read/write rights for you app server or communicate with clients through interface connected to DB, you could accept ID as parameter and get path on the server.